# Restart network PC's services using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need to restart services of a LAN Computer using IP Address. I have this researched:

```
Restart-Service -ComputerName \\10.10.11.16 -ServiceName IETCQRService dnsCache
```

and this is the error I get:

```
Restart-Service : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name
'ComputerName'.
At line:1 char:17
+ Restart-Service -ComputerName \\10.10.11.16 -ServiceName IETCQRServic ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Restart-Service], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RestartServiceCommand
```

I need to use the IP Address because the computer names are the same, they just differ on the IP Address.

**EDIT**
I have used the suggestion but I get this error now:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Service -ComputerName 10.10.11.16 -Name "IETCQRService" | Restart-Service
Get-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'IETCQRService'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Service -ComputerName 10.10.11.16 -Name "IETCQRService" | Restart ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (IETCQRService:String) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
```

Comment: What isn't clear about the new error message? The service you're trying to restart doesn't exist on the computer where you're trying to restart it.

Answer (score 1):

So far as I know, there is no -ComputerName parameter on the Restart-Service command. Instead, you could use something like this:

```
Get-Service -ComputerName 10.10.11.16 -Name "IETCQRService" | Restart-Service
```

You could use both the IP address or the computer name in the Get-Service command

**Note** As pointed out in the comments, this option isn't viable going forward as it is being removed from PowerShell version 6+.

Comment: As far as I'm aware this works only up to PowerShell v5 b/c the parameter `-ComputerName` has since been removed, so this is not a viable approach going forward.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Didn't know that :) thank you for the infomation